# Unexpected performance issue with T-SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL Query:

```
SELECT Wk.WeekID,
       Wk.WeekStart,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NOT(Task.WeekDate IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WeekCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NOT(Task.DayDate IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DayCount
FROM tblPerWeek AS Wk
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPerTask AS Task ON (Task.WeekDate = Wk.WeekStart) 
                                   OR (Task.DayDate BETWEEN Wk.WeekStart AND Wk.WeekEnd)
WHERE (Wk.WeekStart <= @DateEnd) AND (Wk.WeekEnd >= @DateStart)
GROUP BY Wk.WeekID, Wk.WeekStart
```

The structure of `tblPerWeek` table:

```
WeekID int
WeekStart date
WeekEnd date
```

The structure of `tblPerTask` table:

```
TaskID int
WeekDate date
DayDate date
```

Basically, the query counts tasks assigned to week (`WeekCount`) or specific day inside week (`DayCount`).

The `tblPerWeek` has about 2800 records and `tblPerTask` has about 70000 records.

Now, there is some problem/glitch with `(Task.DayDate BETWEEN Wk.WeekStart AND Wk.WeekEnd)` condition in join:

- Without this condition in join the query completes instantly
- With
  this condition in join the query takes about 12 seconds to run

What is the catch? Any solutions on how to make this query faster?

Comment: got indexes on daydate/weekstart/weekend?

Comment: Yes, I have put one index per one date column in both tables, no luck.

Comment: Your join condition involves an `or` so that's not going to be good. Is the first half of it redundant?

Comment: Maybe replace `(Wk.WeekStart <= @DateEnd) AND (Wk.WeekEnd >= @DateStart)` with `Wk.WeekStart between dateadd(dd, -6, @DateStart) and @DateEnd` ?? Looks like you're trying to catch partial weeks or something but I'm not really sure.

Comment: The `@DateStart` and `@DateEnd` occupy more than one week, in fact, i was testing 50 years range.

Comment: I have a kind of solution using `UNION` with two queries without `OR` in join. Wondering if there is something more elegant?

Comment: Are WeekStart and WeekEnd always six days apart? If so then you really only need one of them. Rewrite the queries to use only a single column. That where the `dateadd(dd, -6, ...)` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the problem of using OR is solved by using a UNION query instead. If the two groups of records will be mutually exclusive use UNION ALL which is even faster.

```
SELECT Wk.WeekID,
       Wk.WeekStart,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NOT(Task.WeekDate IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WeekCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NOT(Task.DayDate IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DayCount
FROM tblPerWeek AS Wk
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPerTask AS Task ON Task.WeekDate = Wk.WeekStart
WHERE (Wk.WeekStart <= @DateEnd) AND (Wk.WeekEnd >= @DateStart)
GROUP BY Wk.WeekID, Wk.WeekStart
UNION 
SELECT Wk.WeekID,
       Wk.WeekStart,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NOT(Task.WeekDate IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WeekCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN NOT(Task.DayDate IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DayCount
FROM tblPerWeek AS Wk
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPerTask AS Task ON Task.DayDate BETWEEN Wk.WeekStart AND Wk.WeekEnd
WHERE (Wk.WeekStart <= @DateEnd) AND (Wk.WeekEnd >= @DateStart)
GROUP BY Wk.WeekID, Wk.WeekStart
```

Comment: I don't think union by itself would work. You'll probably have to use union all and then aggregate again.

Comment: Check and see if all of the records in part 1 are also in part two. It is possible that you only need the second query.

Comment: The way the summations are done makes me think there are two different types of tasks being handled by the join and that there is no overlap.

Comment: In one task only one of `WeekDate` or `DayDate` is filled (never both of them)

Comment: The wierd thing that I have now tried `ISNULL(Task.WeekDate, Task.DayDate) BETWEEN Wk.WeekStart AND Wk.WeekEnd` and makes same performance horror.

Comment: Just to mention that aggregate over UNION solution works like a charm, but ugly as hell.

Comment: I still think you should tried my suggestion about not using both WeekStart and WeekEnd. But it doesn't surprised me that that expression is still slow. Union probably makes the most sense given this design.

Comment: I have tried using only `WeekStart` like `dateadd(dd, 6, Wk.WeekStart)` for `WeekEnd`, but still was slow, thanks anyway for suggestion.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it would fix the other problem. I think it might improve the query further by narrowing the range of weeks that have to be scanned.

Comment: And if you've been querying on a 50-year range that's probably most of the 2800 rows. The improvement I was suggesting isn't going to matter until the range is much more narrow.

Answer (score 1):

optimizer hates OR

```
SELECT Wk.WeekID,
       Wk.WeekStart,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TaskW.WeekDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS WeekCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TaskD.DayDate  IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS DayCount
FROM tblPerWeek AS Wk
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPerTask AS TaskW ON TaskW.WeekDate = Wk.WeekStart                                       
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPerTask AS TaskD ON TaskD.DayDate BETWEEN Wk.WeekStart AND Wk.WeekEnd
WHERE Wk.WeekStart <= @DateEnd AND Wk.WeekEnd >= @DateStart
GROUP BY Wk.WeekID, Wk.WeekStart
```

and I think you can just do a count as a count null is 0

```
SELECT Wk.WeekID, Wk.WeekStart,
       COUNT(TaskW.WeekDate) AS WeekCount,
       COUNT(TaskD.DayDate)  AS DayCount
FROM tblPerWeek AS Wk
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPerTask AS TaskW ON TaskW.WeekDate = Wk.WeekStart                                       
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPerTask AS TaskD ON TaskD.DayDate BETWEEN Wk.WeekStart AND Wk.WeekEnd
WHERE Wk.WeekStart <= @DateEnd AND Wk.WeekEnd >= @DateStart
GROUP BY Wk.WeekID, Wk.WeekStart
```

Comment: You know, this is the first thing I tried before even posting question, but probably used only TaskW in both SUM and also worked slow as hell. But now, I have copy/pasted your query and works like a rocket!

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of joins produces kind of cross join between tasks and counts are all wrong.